# How we can pass std::shared_ptr or std::string or std::vectors in objective - C

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, metal

I have following C++ abstract class i have to implement this abstract class in objective C. This interface expects std::shared_ptr and std::vector. Can i implement this class in objectve-C. Or is there any alternative to implement this class in objective-C.
Note: Reason behind implementing this class in objective-C is because i am writing a wrapper for iOS Metal for the defined interface. And iOS metal did not have C++ API it has only objective API.

```
class GPUDevice{ 
 public:
    virtual ~GPUDevice() {

    }
    virtual GPU_TYPE getType() = 0;
    std::vector<GPU_OPERATIONS> supportedGPUOperations{GPU_OPERATIONS::RENDERING,GPU_OPERATIONS::COMPUTE};
    virtual std::shared_ptr<GPUQueue> createQueueForOperation(GPU_OPERATIONS gpuOperations)  = 0;
    virtual std::shared_ptr<GPURenderPass> createRenderPass(GPUTextureFormats formats)  = 0;
    virtual std::shared_ptr<GPUPipeLine> createGPUPipeline(const std::string& fragmentShader, const std::string& vertextShader,const std::shared_ptr<GPURenderPass>& renderpass,const std::vector<GPUBinding>& bindings) = 0; };
```

Comment: You need `Objective-C++` for this. `Objective-C++` sources have `.mm` file extension

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your file from .m to .mm it tells the compiler you are using objective C++. You can use C++ code after that.

Answer (score 0):

To use C++, as other have cited, you'll need to define the file as Objective-C++. One does not need to rename files. Yes, renaming the file to use `.mm` will automatically do this. However, there is another way which is helpful when you have pre-existing files (ie. files already named with `.cpp` or some other C++ extension).

You can change the type to `Objective-C++ Source` in the File Inspector (Available in the menu `View:Inspectors:Show File Inspector` or using the shortcut `Opt+Cmd+1`).

NOTE: If the file is already a `.m` then I do recommend changing the extension to `.mm`.

You'll see the following on the right. Just change Type.

[image]